# Indenting a single paragraph in a document of no indentation

Tags: indentation

I have several paragraphs of text in a LaTeX document. In my preamble I have `\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}`, but now I have a need to indent a single paragraph for emphasis.

I am wondering if there a more efficient way of doing this than:

```
     This paragraph is not indented.
\setlength{\parindent}{15pt}
     Here is my indented paragraph.
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
     And we're back to no indentation.
```

I feel as though there should be a simpler way to do this. Had I not changed the length in my preamble the document would by default indent all the paragraphs, but I could turn this off a single paragraph by using `\noindent` at the start. Why doesn't `\indent` work in the opposite way, and revert that paragraph to the default indentation?

Comment: You can use `\hspace{15pt}` to give you a “hard” indent in that paragraph.

Comment: `\indent` just inserts an empty box of width `\parindent`, so if this is zero nothing is visible. I don't think it's a good idea to use indentation "for emphasis". Either you use it always (with the normal exceptions) or never.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I don't think that using indentation "for emphasis" is a good idea. I prefer indented paragraphs and zero paragraph skip, but I know that somebody has different opinions.

However, I believe that one should either using indentation always (with the usual exceptions, for instance after section titles) or never.

If you really want to confuse your reader `;-)`, here's a way. Note that `\indent` just adds an empty box of width `\parindent`, so if you set the parameter to zero, nothing will be visible. The trick is to reset `\parindent` locally, the closing additional brace will reset it to zero.

```
\documentclass{article}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\newcommand{\forceindent}{\leavevmode{\parindent=1em\indent}}

\begin{document}

This is not indented.

\forceindent This is indented.

This is not indented.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note. Thanks to Frank Mittelbach for having spotted a problem in the simpler solution without `\leavevmode` that would deliver the `\everypar` tokens inside a group. With `\leavevmode` there will be two "indent boxes", one of zero width, followed by what's possibly inserted by `\everypar` and then the new indent box.

Another possibility could be to not doing anything inside a group:

```
\newcommand{\forceindent}{\parindent=1em\indent\parindent=0pt\relax}
```

Comment: Better start with \leavevmode outside the brace group in \forceindent to avoid getting \everypar inside a group.

Answer (score 8):

This is a solution that keeps whatever standard indentation your document class may have for `\myindent`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newlength{\oldparindent}
\setlength{\oldparindent}{\parindent}
\newcommand{\myindent}{\hspace{\oldparindent}}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
%\usepackage{parskip} % potentially a better solution than the line above;
                      % adds some space between paragraphs.

\usepackage{lipsum} % just for dummy text

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\lipsum[1]

\myindent\lipsum[1]

\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

[image: output]