# Left matrix bracket not rendered properly

Tags: xetex, matrices

I am trying to add matrices to an existing document, [here](https://github.com/microsoft/QuantumKatas/blob/master/quickref/qsharp-quick-reference.tex) is the Github page of the original document and [here](https://github.com/microsoft/QuantumKatas/blob/master/quickref/qsharp-quick-reference.pdf) is the rendered version. However, when I add matrices on every other row the left bracket of the matrix is not rendered. This is the result:

[image: incorrectly renderend matrix]

I have tried displaying the brackets in multiple ways however the result always stays the same. This is the current code which I have used:

```latex
Transpose \newline 
    \( \begin{bmatrix}
        a & b \\
        c & d \\
        e & f
    \end{bmatrix}^T \) & 
    \smallskip
    \( \begin{bmatrix}
        a & c & e \\
        b & d & f
    \end{bmatrix} \) \\

    Adjoint \newline    
    \( \begin{bmatrix}
        a & b \\
        c & d \\
        e & f
    \end{bmatrix}^\dagger \) & 
    \smallskip
    \( \begin{bmatrix}
        \overline{a} & \overline{c} & \overline{e} \\
        \overline{b} & \overline{d} & \overline{f}
    \end{bmatrix} \) \\
```

I do not see why this is not rendered properly, especially because it does not happen every row.

Thank you in advance for any help.

**EDIT**

Completely working document

```latex
% Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
% Licensed under the MIT License.

%!TEX program=xelatex
% This cheatsheet is based on the template
% provided at https://gist.github.com/alexander-yakushev/c773543bf9a957749f79.
\documentclass[10pt,english,landscape]{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage[landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{color,graphicx,overpic}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/192067
\usepackage{fontawesome}
  \newfontfamily{\FA}{[FontAwesome.otf]}

% Known issue in {fontspec}: https://github.com/wspr/fontspec/issues/312#issuecomment-342125206
% Since {fontspec} is included only when compiling with XeTeX, we guard
% our fix accordingly.
\usepackage{ifxetex}
    \ifxetex
        \let\latinencoding\relax
        \usepackage{fontspec}
        \setmainfont{Segoe UI}
        \setmonofont{Consolas}
    \fi

% \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
% \usepackage[bitstream-charter]{mathdesign}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{menukeys}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{braket}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\pgfdeclarelayer{background}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfsetlayers{background,main,foreground}

\geometry{top=1cm,left=1cm,right=1cm,bottom=1cm}

\pagestyle{empty} % Turn off header and footer

% \renewcommand\rmdefault{phv} % Arial
% \renewcommand\sfdefault{phv} % Arial

% Redefine section commands to use less space
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\section}{\@startsection{section}{1}{0mm}%
  {-1ex plus -.5ex minus -.2ex}%
  {0.5ex plus .2ex}%x
  {\normalfont\large\bfseries}}
\renewcommand{\subsection}{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{0mm}%
  {-1explus -.5ex minus -.2ex}%
  {0.5ex plus .2ex}%
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\renewcommand{\subsubsection}{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{0mm}%
  {-1ex plus -.5ex minus -.2ex}%
  {1ex plus .2ex}%
  {\normalfont\small\bfseries}}
\makeatother

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0} % Don't print section numbers
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt plus 0.5ex}

\definecolor{TableHead}{rgb}{0.353, 0.329, 0.667}
\definecolor{TableRow}{rgb}{0.816, 0.812, 0.902}

\NewEnviron{keysref}[1]{
  % \begin{center}
  \smallskip
  \begin{tikzpicture}
      \rowcolors{1}{}{TableRow}

      \node (tbl) [inner sep=0pt] {
        \begin{tabular}{p{2.5cm}p{5.05cm}}
          \rowcolor{TableHead}
          \multicolumn{2}{l}{\normalsize\textbf{\color{white}{#1}}}\parbox{0pt}{\rule{0pt}{0.3ex+\baselineskip}}\\
          \BODY
          \arrayrulecolor{TableHead}\specialrule{.17em}{0em}{.2em}
        \end{tabular}};
      \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
        \draw[rounded corners=2pt,top color=TableHead,bottom color=TableHead, draw=white]
        ($(tbl.north west)-(0,-0.05)$) rectangle ($(tbl.north east)-(0.0,0.15)$);
        \draw[rounded corners=2pt,top color=TableHead,bottom color=TableHead, draw=white]
        ($(tbl.south west)-(0.0,-0.11)$) rectangle ($(tbl.south east)-(-0.0,-0.02)$);
      \end{pgfonlayer}
    \end{tikzpicture}
  % \end{center}
}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/102523
\newcommand{\forceindent}[1]{\leavevmode{\parindent=#1\indent}}

%% CUSTOM NOTATION %%

\newcommand{\qs}{Q\#}
\newcommand{\unixlike}{\hfill\faApple\faLinux}
\newcommand{\ctrllike}{\hfill\faWindows\faLinux}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\raggedright\

\Large{\qs~0.10 Language Quick Reference}

\footnotesize
\begin{multicols}{3}



  \begin{keysref}{Linear Algebra}
    Transpose \newline 
    \( \begin{bmatrix}
        a & b \\
        c & d \\
        e & f
    \end{bmatrix}^T \) & 
    \smallskip
    \( \begin{bmatrix}
        a & c & e \\
        b & d & f
    \end{bmatrix} \) \\

    Adjoint \newline    
    \( \begin{bmatrix}
        a & b \\
        c & d \\
        e & f
    \end{bmatrix}^\dagger \) & 
    \smallskip
    \( \begin{bmatrix}
        \overline{a} & \overline{c} & \overline{e} \\
        \overline{b} & \overline{d} & \overline{f}
    \end{bmatrix} \) \\
  \end{keysref}

\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Comment: please post a test document that produces the output shown, it is impossible to debug a fragment as posted

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE. Please edit you post to include a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) starting with a `\documentclass` and ending with a `\end{document}`

Comment: A completely working document can be found in the links, see here: https://github.com/microsoft/QuantumKatas/blob/master/quickref/qsharp-quick-reference.tex

Comment: @DavidCarlisle --- I've made some progress with this question, but my answer isn't really satisfactory. Would you mind taking another look?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I *think* this is some kind of clash between whatever wizardry `xcolor` does for the `\rowcolors` macro, and the double typesetting that `amsmath` uses (first pass measures and second generates the output if I remember correctly). Here is a minimal example that illustrates the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\rowcolors{1}{}{cyan}
\begin{tabular}{c}
AAA\\
\( \begin{bmatrix}                                                                                                                                            
a & b \\                                                                                                                                                      
c & d                                                                                                                                                         
\end{bmatrix} \)                                                                                                                                              
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: bad matrix]

And here is a hack to get around it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newbox\matrixbox
\sbox\matrixbox{\( \begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d
\end{bmatrix} \)}
\begin{document}
\rowcolors{1}{}{cyan}
\begin{tabular}{c}
AAA\\
\usebox\matrixbox
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: good matrix]

The point here is that the problem goes away if the matrix is typeset before attempting to create the table. I'm 99% certain a better method exists, but at the moment I don't know what it is.

Comment: the setbox is probably as good as any, actually it's not due to double typesetting (`bmatrix` is a very thin wrapper around `array` and doesn't use the system used by `align(ed)`) It's simply that the colortbl redefinitions to add the coloured panels have a habit of applying to nested tables

Comment: @Ian Thompson, thank you for your help. I have an updated file which is on github: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/microsoft/QuantumKatas/1499001ba3bfc7c6ec97aa229b24bdefa7e62351/quickref/qsharp-quick-reference.tex. When running this I keep getting `Undefined control sequence` for the boxes, the results still looks good. However, I am not sure if the error could be ignored, do you have any insights on this?

Comment: @vincent --- The easy error: you are missing some dollars on line 93 (going into a `rotatebox` takes you out of math mode). The harder error: I don't really know why you get the `Undefined control sequence` message, but it goes away if you load `amsmath` and `graphicx` first, then do all your sboxes and finally load all your other packages and do everything else. Don't ask why though; there is something going on inside the packages which is beyond my TeX knowledge!

Comment: thank you Ian and especially @vincent

Comment: I have the same clash with ```\rowcolors{2}{white}{white}``` in my document and a ```{bmatrix}``` environment in my appendix (not in a table). Only the left bracket wouldn't render in the pdf. @IanThompson 's comments helped as a work around, but I had more than 5 matrices I would have not bothered with row coloring.